# UISearch NSpredicate filter NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to filter using UISearch and when I filter the NSArray it causes the following error: Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string

Using

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[cd] %@", searchText];
    self.searchResults = [self.pnldArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

array displays as

```
(
        (
        "Section 4 - H15, H19, H26, H42, H43 and H44",
        "Section 5 - H21, H25 and H34"
    ),
        (
        "Section 149(1) - H5487",
        "Section 149(1) - H5491"
    ),
        (
        "Section 146(1) - H5472",
        "Section 147(1) - H5477"
    ),
```

Comment: It sounds like pnldArray isn't an array of strings?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see directly from the thrown exception which types were compared, by looking at the lhs (left hand side) and rhs (right hand side) types.

For example, if your array contained a UIColor object and an NSString with the value "bar", then the exception would be:

*Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string (lhs = UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0 0 1 rhs = bar)*

And since the predicate `beginswith` expects objects of type NSString, any other types of object will cause the predicate to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You *may* want:

```
NSPredicate*    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF beginswith[cd] %@", searchText];
```

I say may because it's not particularly clear what results you expect.  The predicate given will return an array of arrays of strings (same format as you started with) where only the arrays that contain the target string are returned (in their entirety)

If, instead, you want only the strings that contain your search text to be returned either in some flattened array or otherwise, you've got more work ahead of you.